# Sentence reverse loop is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reverse the sentence by using a loop. It looks like with every iteration the letter that I add to the end of the sentence is disappearing. Don’t know what is wrong. I am aware of `.split(“”).reverse().join(“”)` but need to use a loop here. Any help would be great.

```js
var sntn = "Once upon a time in a village called 'Vlasovo'";
var sntnSplit = sntn.split("");
var lmt = sntnSplit.length;

for (i = 0; i < lmt; i++) {
  sntnSplit[lmt - i] = sntnSplit[0];
  sntnSplit.splice(0, 1);
}

console.log(sntnSplit);
```

Comment: do you want to reverse characters OR words?

Comment: I need to reverse the sentence like in a mirrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `Array.splice`, it's removing the elements from your array. Therefore it only contains the last char when the loop is finished.

You could simply run the loop "backwards".

```js
var input = "Once upon a time in a village called 'Vlasovo'";

for(var i = input.length - 1, output = ''; i >= 0; --i) {
  output += input[i];
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what [you want reverse](https://jsfiddle.net/quehf3x9/7/) the stringgiven??

```
var sntn = "Once upon a time in a village called 'Vlasovo'";
var sntnSplit = sntn.split("");
var lmt = sntnSplit.length; 
console.log(sntnSplit.reverse().join(''));
```

Comment: the exercise is to purposedly use a loop (split -> reverse -> join is explicitly stated as not correct)

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze what your code does, for a shorter string like `"abcd"`

```js
var sntn = "abcd";
var sntnSplit = sntn.split(""); // = ['a','b','c','d']
var lmt = sntnSplit.length; // = 4

// unroll the loop part
// for(i=0; i<lmt; i++) { i: 0 -> 4
var i = 0;
// lmt - i == 4
sntnSplit[lmt - i] = sntnSplit[0]; // sntnSplit = ['a','b','c','d','a'];
sntnSplit.splice(0,1); // sntnSplit = ['b','c','d','a'];
// lmt - i == 3
i = 1
sntnSplit[lmt - i] = sntnSplit[0]; // sntnSplit =  ['b','c','d','b'];
sntnSplit.splice(0,1); // sntnSplit = ['c','d','a'];
i = 2
// lmt - i == 2
sntnSplit[lmt - i] = sntnSplit[0]; // sntnSplit = ['c','d','c'];
sntnSplit.splice(0,1); // sntnSplit = ['d','c'];
i = 3
// lmt - i == 1
sntnSplit[lmt - i] = sntnSplit[0]; // sntnSplit = ['d','d'];
sntnSplit.splice(0,1); // sntnSplit = ['d'];

console.log(sntnSplit)
```

if you analyse what each line of your code does, it is pretty clear what's wrong.

Comment: But the length of the string should be the same cause I add a letter with every iteration, so splice is compensated by this added letter

Comment: I could give you 100 examples of correct algorithms, but you should be trying to understand what's wrong with the one you wrote, to be a better programmer. Try to repeat my analysis, check if every step actually makes sense, and you'll understand why your code is wrong. Please spend at least half as much time reading my answer as I spent writing it.

Comment: I appreciate your help and will work with your reply properly. Thank you)

Answer (score -1):

With a for loop as you wanted. You just had to go from length downwards

```
let c = "Once upon a time in a village called 'Vlasovo'".split("");
let s = '';
for(let i = c.length; i>=0; i--) {
 s+=c[i]
}
```

// Not tested, though it must work

Comment: You should've tested it, because it's not working correctly, `c.length` as index is outside of the array. You have to use `c.length - 1`.